# Tableau server - Snowflake (50311) UTF-8 Error

Tags: utf-8, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, tableau-api

I am able to run the extract successfully in Tableau Desktop, over the Tableau server intermittently I am getting errors with the message

> "java.lang.RuntimeException: [Snowflake][Support] (50311) Error converting invalid input with source encoding UTF-8 using ICU. Rejected bytes began with: ACFF."**.

Are there any settings over the Tableau server that I can enable to get rid of this error. Kindly assist.

Comment: This is more of a encoding related error for the data in Snowflake table. Are you using Native Snowflake Driver for Tableau or the native ODBC driver? There has been a similar case reported earlier here: https://community.snowflake.com/s/question/0D50Z00009Y7ExfSAF/i-am-getting-this-error-when-trying-to-retrieve-data-from-a-table-using-odbc-driverhy000-native-error-code-50311-snowflakesupport-50311-error-converting-invalid-input-with-source-encoding-utf8-using-icu-rejected-bytes-began-with-924d

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on error code I assume you're using Snowflake ODBC driver. If that is the case, check if the result set is set to 'ARROW' (by default it is):

```
SHOW PARAMETERS LIKE 'ODBC_QUERY_RESULT_FORMAT';
```

Change result set format to 'JSON' and see if you're still getting the error (should not happen):

```
ALTER USER <user> SET ODBC_QUERY_RESULT_FORMAT='JSON';
```

Comment: The error got fixed and It worked as expected. Thanks for it @sergiu.